# How to add NVMe drivers to an SSD to a cloned Windows installation to use in new computer so the system can boot?

Tags: windows, windows-7, drivers, ssd, clone

I used a disc cloning software to clone a non-nvme drive into an NVMe drive.

The problem is that I need to add a couple drivers for Windows to boot. Namely, the NVMe drivers. This includes 2 hotfixes and 1 Samsung SSH driver.

My old installation of Windows 7 is set up how I like it already. I don't want to start over, I would like to save 1-2 days of work (that's how long it takes to configure everything).

I have the drivers I need. I slipstreamed the drivers into a Windows install disc and it worked, proving that I have the right drivers, so I'm able to install Windows 7 on this NVMe drive. But I don't want a clean install.

I'm using a live cd and can copy any files I need and I also have command prompt if needed. The old drive is fully cloned onto the new drive, I just need the drivers.

How can I add the drivers and hotfixes for NVMe into the new cloned Windows installation without a reinstall?

**Update**: I solved the issue, and posted the answer, which I spent a lot of time on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to slipstream the drivers using CMD from a live CD directly into the installation, after slipstreaming the drivers into the USB stick's `boot.wim` file on the usb.

If you don't slipstream into the USB stick itself, it might not be able to read your disk, for example, Windows 7 does not include NVMe drivers so you need to add the two hotfixes and the drivers.

**THE TRICK:** You can directly mount a full windows install using `dism`.

When you boot from a live CD (I used AOMEI USB environment which uses WinPE), make sure it can see the drive. As long as your recovery environment can see the drive over command prompt, you can slipstream the drivers and packages/hotfixes directly into a fully installed windows installation.

Open the CMD in the recovery environment, and first check where your windows is installed.

First check what drives are attached:

```
diskpart

list disk
```

If your disk is listed then you are good to continue. If not, then you need to put the right drivers, such as nvme drivers, into your recovery USB. You can use dism like shown below to directly slipstream the USB stick by finding the boot.wim (usually in /sources/boot.wim) and slipstreaming.

Once you get your disk listed, exit parted

```
exit
```

Now check which disk windows is installed on:

```
cd C:\

dir
```

`dir` will tell you what's in that directory making it clear if it's the windows root directory or not. For CMD it's the same as `ls` in a linux terminal.

If it's not in C:\ *(probably won't be because it will probaby be the boot partition which WinPE will mount as the first drive letter)*, do the same for each drive letter until you find it. Mine was `D:\`

```
cd D:\

dir
```

Once you found the correct partition for the root of your windows install *(the one with "Program Files" directory)*, now it's time to slipstream the drivers.

Make sure that you have another drive installed, or you copied the drivers somewhere you can access. Might even work to copy the drivers and pacakages folder into the root of your windows install.

I put them in a folder called `tmp` which I put in the root of an external USB drive.

I put the windows hotfixes in `E:\tmp\hotfix` in my case. I put the drivers in `E:\tmp\drivers`. Of course, you need to do this ahead of time or from another computer.

Then `dism` will find any hotfixes and drivers you put in there and install them all. Install like below.

Mount the image using `dism`. The `/Image:D:\` part is the trick. YOU CAN MOUNT THE INSTALLED WINDOWS DISK IN DISM! That is the not-obvious trick.

```
dism /Mount-Image /Image:D:\ /Add-Package /PackagePath:E:\tmp\hotfix

dism /Image:D:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:E:\tmp\drivers /Recurse /forceunsigned

dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\tmp\mount /Commit
```

If the above gives an error that says `Mount-Image` doesn't work, it is using the older version of `dism`. In that case, use `/Mount-Wim`

```
dism /Mount-Wim /Image:D:\ /Add-Package /PackagePath:E:\tmp\hotfix

dism /Image:D:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:E:\tmp\drivers /Recurse /forceunsigned

dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\tmp\mount /Commit
```

You can also run this to get the help to see what the correct commands are for your version of `dism` in case of any issues:

```
dism /?
```

After slipstreaming all the drivers and packages you need, you should be able to boot into the disk, it might ask you to reboot after finishing the install on the first boot. It worked for me.

The real secret to this all is the fact **you can simply mount an entire windows installation partition** in the same way as a `boot.wim` file.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same situation here: Windows 7 on a HD cloned to a NVMe. It started to boot, then a Blue Screen of Death appeared.

**THE PROBLEM**

After seeing this Question, and several others, I discovered that the problem was a missing hotfix for my Kingston NVMe on Windows 7.

**SOLUTION**

My solution was "simple":

1. Booted on the Win7 on the HD;
2. Downloaded and installed the hotfix **KB2990941** — if you can't find it, [try this link](https://forums.geshl2.com/index.php?topic=8950.0);
3. Re-cloned the windows, but only the partition with the Windows (C:) (of course that you can clone everything again, it will just take more time).

Now it is working!

**OBSERVATIONS**

**1.** I did the cloning using Linux Mint with **dd**. Check this [link for more information](https://www.tecmint.com/clone-linux-partitions/).

**2.** On the HD's Win7, I made sure that I could see the NVMe device before re-cloning it. I did not appeared on "My Computer", because of the ID beeing the same (after the clone process), but at the Device Manager it appeared;

**2.1.** Also I could not boot the NVMe with the HD connected, probably because of the ID, but it was not a problem, because I just needed the NVMe there.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 Boot from windows install USB stick or DVD  (You may have to use that CD you created with the driver slip streamed)

Step 2 use F8 or F10 or maybe Shift F10 get a command prompt(Windows 7 it maybe Repair and then command prompt)

Step 3

Replace C:\ with whatever the drive letter of the C: is in this special mode

Replace c:\drivers with the folder that contains the drivers.

```
dism /image:c:\ /Add-driver /Driver:c:\drivers /Recurse /forceunsigned
```

Step 4 Reboot and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, had cloned a SSD to a NVME and could not for the life of me get it to boot to Windows 10.  Tried all the answers above with no luck, it wanted the drivers from the Intel Rapid Storage Technology set up.  I was able to load those (had added them to the installer USB stick) while in windows install set up from a USB install in the custom drive set up screen, exiting before install and going to console in the recovery area of the USB installer.  DiskPart could then see the NVME.  Tried the commands above with no luck.

The only solution I found was to put the NVME into an external USB NVME enclosure, boot into that with safe mode and then install Intel Rapid Storage Technology.  What a mess this all is but that worked, hopefully that will help someone.  Cheers

Comment: Not really an answer but a forum style "me too" comment with an additional step that looks like a solution, and alternative to the other proper answers already posted but it's only applicable in a very specific scenario.