# Windows 7 installation log Location

Tags: windows-7, installation, logging

Lately I've been encountering errors with my Windows 7 installation on my computer is there a location in which the Windows 7 Installation media logs the installation process? If so can you please provide the directory of where the logs may be located.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Maybe you could post examples of errors your encountered.

Comment: Yes it's this Error: https://s28.postimg.org/buagjdxxp/img_5751005d9e1c2.png

Comment: I've been trying to make a USB media installation of windows 7 SP1 (BTW I've already integrated USB 2.0/3.0/3.1 drivers into the Boot.wim and updates into the install.wim).


the problem seems to only be presented on My MSI GE62 6QD Laptop. Otherwise this installation media works completely fine on other laptops with no errors.


If you would like a Copy of my project for analysis feel free to request and i'll post a link.

Comment: add USB3 and SATA/nvme drivers to boot.wim. also make sure you selected index 2 for boot.wim, not 1.

Comment: I added USB 3.0 for both indexes

Comment: Where do I find the SATA/nvme. Is it in a directory or where can i find it on the internet

Comment: NVMe is a protocol like AHCI.if you use a [M2 SSD with NVme protocol you need to do more step to install Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/1116984/174557).

Comment: Well i don't have a SSD but I tried integrating Intel Rapid storage driver which was for my SATA HDD and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this list, since in different phase of installation, there are several logs created to record the process: 
For details you can refer to this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744583(v=ws.10).aspx

$windows.~bt\Sources\Panther
Log location before Setup can access the drive.
$windows.~bt\Sources\Rollback
Log location when Setup rolls back in the event of a fatal error.
%WINDIR%\Panther
Log location of Setup actions after disk configuration.
%WINDIR%\Inf\Setupapi*.log
Used to log Plug and Play device installations.
%WINDIR%\Memory.dmp
Location of memory dump from bug checks.
%WINDIR%\Minidump*.dmp
Location of log minidumps from bug checks.
%WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther
Location of Sysprep logs.

Comment: This event happen way before the Windows 7 Installation check the disk or enter any details so could it be in

%WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther ?